# When to use pixels vs. percentages when it comes to CSS layout (especially with re-sizing window)?

Tags: html, css

My most recent problem has been with my websites looking fine when the browser is full-screened, but looking absolutely awful when it gets smaller. I sort of design by making it look good while it's fullscreen, so I have no idea what to do to make sure that it will also look good when the window is a different size.

Here is what I'm currently working on (fullscreen):

[image]

Here is the same page when the browser is half of my screen width:

[image]

Obviously it looks a lot neater when in fullscreen.

My question is: **How do I fix these problems in advance when starting a website from the beginning? When do I use pixels vs. percentages?**

I know of media queries, but I feel like I'd have to add a bunch to make sure this website always looks good no matter what the window size is. Is that just something that web developers have to do? Is there a better way?

Just for good measure, here is the HTML for these three divs:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            HEADER
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div id="encomp">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>
                Sidebar
            </h2>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
                <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            MAIN CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#header {
background-color: #cb2424; 
font-size: 50px; 
text-align: center;
width: 70%;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 10px;
letter-spacing: .75em;}

#header h1 {
color: white;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;}

#sidebar { 
float: left; 
width: 200px; 
background-color: #cb2424; 
min-height: 400px;
margin: 0 35px 35px;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;}

#main {
background: blue;
min-height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
border-radius: 10px;}
```

I believe I've included all of the code necessary. I left out some of the internal workings of the sidebar code just so I wouldn't clutter this up more than I already have but if more information is required, please let me know.

Also, if anyone has any links to any articles where I could learn CSS layout better, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't have a hard answer. It would only be based on opinion. There's many ways to do things. I would suggest checking out theses sites and many others like them.

http://alistapart.com/

http://css-tricks.com/

Also do a google search for the term "responsive." That should get you started :)

EDIT: You should also consider the possibility of using a framework like bootstrap, foundation, or pure.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I know this question is kinda hard to answer, but I figure I would try anyways. Thank you for the links, I'll be sure to check those out!

Comment: A common solution is to use percentages for `height` and `width`, and then use `min-XXX` and `max-XXX` wiht pixels to prevent them from getting too extreme when you resize the window.

Comment: That's a good idea! I always forget to do that, but I've seen it used before. Thank you, I'll definitely use that advice in the future.

Comment: Easiest is always use percentage for `width` or `left` and pixels for `height` or `top`, and as for your problem, what you can do is keep your code as it is, just add `min-width` etc for the body to make it stop changing its size when the elements reach the point of overlapping.